# How to redirect stderr for openvt

Tags: linux, bash, tty

I have to launch my TextUI daemon respawning on a specific tty. For that purpose I launch it from a script, like this: `$set_tty $launch_app`, where

- `set_tty="openvt -c1 -s -w"`,
- `launch_app="my_daemon 2>'$HOME'/logfile"`

This way I get launched the command looking like `openvt -c1 -s -w my_daemon 2>'$HOME'/logfile`, which redirects to the specified logfile only the stderr from the `openvt` itself, but not from my daemon.

How is it supposed to redirect the `openvt`'s callee stderr?

I tried using function:

```
go () { my_daemon 2>"$HOME"/logfile; }
openvt -c1 -s -w
```

It does not work, opentty immediately returns control spawning nothing.

I tried `exec 2>>"$HOME"/logfile`

I tried launching a separate script, with that function. The script failed to run via openvt, but ran OK if I launched it manually with same parameters.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible answer is likely a wrapper shell script, the contents of which would be responsible for spawning your daemon, and redirecting `stderr` to a log file you choose.

```
[anew@bucket ~]$ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo "Testing openvt" > /tmp/openvt-example

[anew@bucket ~]$ sudo openvt -c7 -s -w /home/anew/test.sh
[anew@bucket ~]$ cat /tmp/openvt-example
Testing openvt
[anew@bucket ~]$
```

Comment: OK, I'll check that on Thursday, when I am back again to that system I have to set up. I've tried this, must have screwed up somewhere, then.
Thank you!

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to `chmod +x` my script.